# youtube video playlists not working on android (only one video plays)

Tags: android, browser, youtube, playlist

problem : playlists do not play on mobile devices when launched from websites via the browser or via the youtube app.

note : Only AS3 players (version 3) are listed in documentation as compatible with playlists.

The different tests below that work normally on the windows vista pc using either a) firefox browser version 27, or b) google chrome browser Version 27.0.1453.110 m. These test are here: http://myyogavideo.com/test5.php

No playlists work properly (display multiple videos in a row) using the browser or youtube app on android jellybean (on a samsung Galaxy SIII) ... usually only the first video is shown.

Here are various examples of code that does not work:

[Launch You Tube Video Player App](http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLRglkGMmdY_UZhd0rrWMrxYgKi0G9Tq2U&version=3)

thanks

Steve